# Make read-only file read write from commandline windows

Tags: windows, command-line, file-permissions

How can I make a read-only Windows file read+write for Everyone from the command line.  I searched CACLS but the examples aren't great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [attrib](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) command:

here is an example

> attrib -r file.txt

This would remove the read-only attribute from the file called file.txt